# React Hooks - prevent re-render, but act on the new props

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that displays a web map.  I need to pass data in and out of the map component, but I *never* need to re-render it.  I do all my work on the map outside of react - working directly with the mapping library.

Using functional components and hooks, how can I pass props in, act on them, and get data out of this component without rerendering?  I've tried a combo of `useEffect()` and `memo()`, but they end up canceling out each other's use:

I have useEffect watching for changes of the relevant props and memo blocking renders, but since memo blocks renders, and useEffect only fires after a render, I have no way of handling prop updates in this component.

```
const Map = memo(props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // run this on props update
    console.log(props.selectedImg);
  }, [props.selectedImg]);

  //... map lib specific code using props

  return <div id="mapDiv" />;
  }, 
  //prevent all rerenders using memo..
  () => true
);
```

This doesn't work because memo prevents re-render and so useEffect is never fired even though props are updated.

How can I use hooks to work with props while entirely preventing this component from re-rendering?  Perhaps this structure is not correct at all.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you pass the data in and out using AJAX? That way the components would not re-render at all.

Comment: This is a good question.  It's a workaround, but if the map element itself never has to re-render or receive props, have you tried just separating ```#mapDiv``` into its own component and preventing all re-renders on that? Not sure if that will cause issues with the map library.

Comment: Try removing this:   `//prevent all rerenders using memo..  () => true` as it will always  return true meaning nextProps and oldProps are equal.

Comment: @Rikin I need to return true there in order to prevent the re-render though.

Comment: @ShaneLoeffler I guess you can compare in that call back your desired prop value and return false conditionally if `selectedImg` changed

Comment: Right but that would cause a re-render of the component, which I do not want to do.  I just want to grab the new selectedImg from props and pass it into some map-specific functions without updating the component itself.

Comment: Which is what you may be able to do in the callback I guess and then always pass true to not re-render

Comment: @Rikin that's a solid idea - I'll give it a go. Thanks!